# What is the different between io.swagger.annotations and com.wordnik.swagger.annotations

Tags: swagger

I am new to swagger and found there are two packages for swagger annotation:  io.swagger.annotations and com.wordnik.swagger.annotations. I wonder what the difference is between them and what I should use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are different versions of swagger which go with different versions of other supporting software stack that you might be using.

I too came across these two a month ago when trying to integrate my application with swagger ui. I was using cxf 2.7.11, jackson 2.6.0 with spring 3.0.7 . I struggled a lot with com.wordnik (older version where swagger json is generated at url api_docs with usage of ApiListingResource etc) but then thought of implementing io.swagger (newer version) just to see the difference. Turned out that was the version i should have been using in the first place. Everything fell in place after that.

Answer (score 10):

The `com.wordnik` package is for the older swagger specifications, 1.x.  As of swagger specification 2.0, the package is now `io.swagger`.  The annotation signatures should be the same, just the package has changed.

Answer (score 2):

One addition in case others were wondering, too:

We used swagger version 1.3.13 which was called `swagger-core_2.10`. Initially I thought this may indicate a swagger API 2.X compatibility which it actually isn't: 2.10 is the bundled Scala version (mentioned [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup)) This means means **25 MB** of [unecessary](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/624) dependenies! So the [current](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) swagger version 1.5.X was rewritten in pure java and is much smaller in size. The scala version was moved to a [separate project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-scala-module).